# how to mount a data center storage on a server so an user can access it remotely?

Tags: ssh, permissions, mount, scp, cifs

I need to mount a storage on server A so that from server B, I can send a file via scp from B to A.

On server A, I am trying to mount the storage as:

`# mount.cifs //u999999.your-storagebox.de/backup /storage/driveNumber -v -o user=u999999,pass=typeUrPasswordHere`

The mount result is:

```
# ls -la /storage 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Feb  2 17:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root   4096 Feb  2 17:16 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 999999 999999    0 Feb  3 17:26 bx20_133060
```

But, when I try to send the file from server B (my box for now), I get this:

```
$ scp -v -p -P 45789 mysql-incremental.tar.gz slammer@d2.wearebionic.com:/storage/bx20_133060
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host d2.wearebionic.com, user slammer, command scp -v -p -t /storage/bx20_133060
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to d2.wearebionic.com [136.243.80.14] port 45789.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gtl/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to d2.wearebionic.com:45789 as 'slammer'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ue89Au5xEc1UIDcLMwNhTGWuHP7vwJwNHtQbaYo0cUI
debug1: Host '[d2.wearebionic.com]:45789' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gtl/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/gtl/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to d2.wearebionic.com ([136.243.80.14]:45789).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = pt_BR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_IE.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -p -t /storage/bx20_133060
File mtime 1485968603 atime 1486140418
Sending file timestamps: T1485968603 0 1486140418 0
Sink: T1485968603 0 1486140418 0
Sending file modes: C0777 75337 mysql-incremental.tar.gz
Sink: C0777 75337 mysql-incremental.tar.gz
scp: /storage/bx20_133060/mysql-incremental.tar.gz: Permission denied
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3336, received 2708 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 13686.3, received 11109.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

What am I doing wrong and how to get it right?

Comment: You need to simplify in order to troubleshoot.  From `d2.wearebionic.com`, if you log in as `slammer`, can you write new files to `/storage/bx20_133060`?  If so, what does `ls -l /storage/bx20_133060/mysql-incremental.tar.gz` show you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for just using `scp`  I would first validate it between server A and server B directly and take your `storagebox` out of the equation.

From each server try something like  `scp    somefile.txt    otherserver:/home/gtludwig/`

If that does not work then the problem is more simplified and has to do with `ssh` and `scp` and the security between each server.

But I suspect the problem lies with user, file, and directory permissions not being sync'd between the `storagebox` and that of the server you are mounting it to.  This would be especially true if `storagebox` being cifs is some storage device that **authenticates** with some Windows Domain Server... which would technically be Server C.  Also know the admin of `storagebox` can simply restrict what devices can mount `storagebox` regardless if the username & password are correct for `storagebox`.  This would be the equivalent of restricting a linux NFS export to given hosts as might be specified in `/etc/exports`.

But from the info you provided it looks like what is happening is you have `storagebox` mounted on `server_A` and a mount.cifs is directed under user `u999999`  but when using `scp` you are SSH'ing into Server_A under user `slammer` thus permission denied.

From Server_A first make sure `storagebox` is successfully mounted, and then as user `u999999` you can then successfully upload a file to `storagebox`.  Then try `scp` into server_A as `u999999`, or make sure the username/userid you use for `scp` is the same as that used for mounting the cifs share.